# closed or open parentheses checker

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write  program to determine whether or not a mathematical expression contains matching parentheses. I need to check if they have the same amount of left vs right, and then from that determine if they are open. But I'm not sure how to do that. After I get the expression, nothing comes out. I know there is a better way to find out if they are closed... but I can't figure it out

an example of an expression they could check would be (5+5)/(5+2-5), or something like that

```
def main():
  left = 0
  right = 0
  even = (0 or 2 or 4 or 6 or 8 or 10 or 12 or 14) #is there a better way to check if they match rather than doing even or odd?
  odd = (1 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 9 or 11 or 13 or 15)
  if expression == "(": 
    left += 1
  elif expression == ")":
    right -= 1
  expression = input("write a mathematical expression with parentheses") #lets user input mathematical expression to evaluate for correct number of parentheses
  parentheses = (left + right) #this is probably not the most efficient way, I just want to find out if my parentheses match, so suggestions here would help
  if parentheses == even: 
    print("Your parentheses are closed")
  if parentheses == odd:
    print("You are missing a parenthese")




main()
```

Comment: What can your expression look like?  Give us an example?

Comment: You do know you're not iterating over your expression string?

Comment: just something that has parentheses, like (1-9)*4

Comment: And that you're testing for `even` or `odd` before evaluating the expression.

Comment: What does that mean? How do I iterate it?

Comment: lol oops, this is so messy. I'm so tired and its due at midnight

Comment: You want to evaluate your `expression` character by character, to see if it's ( or ).  When you're done with that, and you've updated your counts, THEN you can check if it's even or not.

Comment: Seeing if I can fix it up a little with some comments - give me a few?

Comment: I tried to add some comments... I'm not sure that thats what you were looking for. Honestly have no idea what I'm doing here

Comment: The user should input the mathematical expression; output should show whether or not the expression has matching parentheses. If not, the program should tell which parentheses are missing. Let the user repeat the program as many times as desired, until "stop" is typed as the expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in your code:

1. You need to iterate over each character in your input string (`expression`) to see if it's a parenthesis or something else, and then count them.
2. You need to do *1* before deciding whether parentheses are closed or open
3. Not a problem per se, but you can test whether something is even with the modulo operator `%`, rather than defining even and odd variables.
4. There are a couple of inefficiencies and unnecessary variables in your code

The code below should do what you're after:

```
def main():
    left = 0
    right = 0
    expression = raw_input("write a mathematical expression with parentheses: ")
    for character in expression:
        if character == '(':
            left = left + 1
        elif character == ')':
            right = right + 1

    total = left + right
    if (left < right):
        missing = "left"
    elif (right < left):
        missing = "right"
    if (total % 2) == 0:
        print("Your parentheses are closed")
    else:
        print("You are missing a " + missing + " parentheses")

main()
```

Comment: Is there a way that I could say which one was missing?

Comment: Sure - check which of `left` or `right` is smaller, and that's your missing one.  Updated.